# DataContext of Window cannot be found for DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, devexpress

I've looked through a few articles but none of them seem to fix my problem.

I'm trying to bind the visibility of a Wait Indicator control.
My first try was this

```
<dx:LoadingDecorator Panel.ZIndex="5"
                     DataContext="{Binding}"
                     SplashScreenDataContext="{Binding}">
    <dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <dx:WaitIndicator DeferedVisibility="{Binding IsActive}" 
                      Content="Loading" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>

    <!-- TreeList... -->

</dx:LoadingDecorator>
```

That didn't work, according to the log it can't find the value because the DataItem is null.

```
Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:IsActive; DataItem=null; target element is 'WaitIndicator' (Name=''); target property is 'DeferedVisibility' (type 'Boolean')
```

(Fun fact, if I use `F12` after selecting `IsActive`, Visual Studio jumps to the correct Property in the correct Viewmodel)

After that, I tried to reference the `DataContext` directly like this

```
<dx:LoadingDecorator Panel.ZIndex="5"
                     DataContext="{Binding}"
                     SplashScreenDataContext="{Binding}">
    <dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <dx:WaitIndicator DeferedVisibility="{Binding ElementName=ParentWindow, Path=DataContext.IsActive, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
                      Content="Loading" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>

    <!-- TreeList... -->

</dx:LoadingDecorator>
```

Where `ParentWindow` is defined like this

```
<DXWindow x:Name="ParentWindow" />
```

and the `DataContext` as usual like this

```
<dx:DXWindow.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</dx:DXWindow.DataContext>
```

That doesn't work either, the log shows this

```
Created BindingExpression (hash=23511423) for Binding (hash=8575450)
  Path: 'DataContext.IsActive'
BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Default mode resolved to OneWay
BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Attach to DevExpress.Xpf.Core.WaitIndicator.DeferedVisibility (hash=24910686)
BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Resolving source 
BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
    Lookup name ParentWindow:  queried WaitIndicator (hash=24910686)
 BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Resolve source deferred
    Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.IsActive; DataItem=null; target element is 'WaitIndicator' (Name=''); target property is 'DeferedVisibility' (type 'Boolean')
 BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Resolving source 
 BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
     Lookup name ParentWindow:  queried WaitIndicator (hash=24910686)
 BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Resolving source 
 BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
     Lookup name ParentWindow:  queried WaitIndicator (hash=24910686)
 BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Resolving source  (last chance)
 BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
     Lookup name ParentWindow:  queried WaitIndicator (hash=24910686)
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ParentWindow'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.IsActive; DataItem=null; target element is 'WaitIndicator' (Name=''); target property is 'DeferedVisibility' (type 'Boolean')
```

These two lines look interesting to me:

```
BindingExpression (hash=23511423): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
    Lookup name ParentWindow:  queried WaitIndicator (hash=24910686)
```

Why is the `DataContext` null? Is there anything else I'm missing?

---

**edit**

After adapting the changes from @Andy the property got bound correctly but there's still something missing. The UI doesn't update. I'm sure the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event is implemented correctly.
The log prints this:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=1669504) for Binding (hash=32903719)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'IsActive'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): Attach to DevExpress.Xpf.Core.WaitIndicator.DeferedVisibility (hash=14696841)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): Activate with root item MainWindowViewModel (hash=42302050)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504):   At level 0 - for MainWindowViewModel.IsActive found accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsActive)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): Replace item at level 0 with MainWindowViewModel (hash=42302050), using accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsActive)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): GetValue at level 0 from MainWindowViewModel (hash=42302050) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsActive): 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): TransferValue - using final value 'False'
```

Looks good so far - the Viewmodel can be found. 
However, this line still seems to be a problem.

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=1669504): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
```

the updated XAML looks like this

```
<dx:LoadingDecorator Panel.ZIndex="5"
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 Grid.Column="1">
    <dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate  >
        <DataTemplate >
            <dx:WaitIndicator 
                    DeferedVisibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=mainVM}, 
                        Path=IsActive, 
                        diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                        NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Content="Loading" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
```

Looks like there's still something wrong.

---

**edit 2:**
I ended up using the `WaitIndicator` directly, without a `DataTemplate`. It works and produces the wanted output. However, I still don't understand why my initial approach doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check if with `RelativeSource` work ? --- `DeferedVisibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsActive, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dx:DXWindow}}}"`

Comment: @user1672994 I've already tried that, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Datacontext is marked as inherits so any control in the visual tree of your window will inherit the datacontext of the window which is vm:MainWindowViewModel.

It seems this control is not in the visual tree which means it can't find the datacontext.

Once you moved the viewmodel from window resources and referenced it from there.

```
<Window ......    

     DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewmodel x:Key="vm"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

That still didn't work.

Meaning the template is applied outside of the window somehow. Without knowing more about what the control is and how the template is applied that's all I can say.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either, the found Datacontext is still null.

Comment: Whatever your control is, it's not in the visual tree. Move the vm instance to window resources.

Comment: Good point, I've adapted your changes. Can you please take a look at my edit in the post?

Comment: Looks like you bound deferedvisibility to the entire viewmodel. You need a path=yourproperty, on the binding before source=. Note that the comma

Comment: I already have that one, in the line directly under deferedvisibility. It's just formatted a bit weirdly.

Comment: I ended up using a different approach which works, I've simply used the ```WaitingIndicator``` directly without a ```DataTemplate```. I still don't understand why the initial try didn't work, though.

Comment: I recommend you install snoop ( it's free ) and you can then easily examine property values on ui at run time, see when events are firing etc.